# Make full width image which won't take space

Tags: html, css

I have a code like this -

```html
<span class="cropper-view-box" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
<img src="https://www.popsci.com/sites/popsci.com/files/styles/1000_1x_/public/images/2018/03/senna.jpg" style="width: 100%;opacity: 0.5;">

<img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/59bafdf204afdc5248726f5c/master/w_2400,c_limit/BMW-TA.jpg" style="width: 466.667px; height: 350px;">
</span>
```

I would like the first image not to take any space. So the 2nd image would be on top of the first image. But the first image should have 100% width of the span. How to achieve that? Tried position absolute and left:0, no help.

Comment: As a code style: Don't use inline styles.  Ever.  Please.  For the love of everything good and Holy.  It is not good....

Comment: @cale_b I normally don't in my code. The whole code was literally huge and these elements were generated by jQuery. So I just created something similar to what I am experiencing in few lines and put inline-css here. But next time, I will put the css in css snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there. You need both: `left:0;` and `top:0;` to get it in the left right corner. I think this is what you're looking for:

```html
<span class="cropper-view-box" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
<img src="https://www.popsci.com/sites/popsci.com/files/styles/1000_1x_/public/images/2018/03/senna.jpg" style="width: 100%;opacity: 0.5;">

<img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/59bafdf204afdc5248726f5c/master/w_2400,c_limit/BMW-TA.jpg" style="width: 466.667px; height: 350px; position:absolute; left:0; top:0;">
</span>
```

If you want to make sure the span keeps within the 500 width and 500 height. Add: `display:block;`. This makes the span act like a div. Then you will get this:

```html
<span class="cropper-view-box" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; display:block;">
<img src="https://www.popsci.com/sites/popsci.com/files/styles/1000_1x_/public/images/2018/03/senna.jpg" style="width: 100%;opacity: 0.5;">

<img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/59bafdf204afdc5248726f5c/master/w_2400,c_limit/BMW-TA.jpg" style="width: 466.667px; height: 350px; position:absolute; left:0; top:0;">
</span>
```

In addition:

- Please consider adding a style sheet to add your styles and use classes just like you did for `cropper-view-box`.

Comment: thanks, I have stylesheet. I wrote the code like this here to make it appear simple. And it worked

Comment: I added some information about `display:block;`. I hope this helps you out. :)

Comment: @AsifurRahman In the future, post the CSS separately in the window that you can use in the Snippet builder. It's easier for us to debug that way.

Comment: @BramVanroy so sorry for this, I will do that next time.